# How can I make My Program Wait for a TouchEvent In Android

Tags: android

I am facing a problem. I have written down code to select the white ball now I want to make my program wait for another Touch On the screen.

After This line `WhiteBall.ball.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);`

The ball is selected now i want to make my program wait for another touch that will define the speed of the ball, How can I make my program wait for a Touch?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    int xpos=(int) e.getX();
    int ypos=(int) e.getY();

    if(WhiteBall.velocity==0)
        if((xpos>WhiteBall.x-30 && xpos<WhiteBall.x+30) && (ypos>WhiteBall.y-30 && ypos<WhiteBall.y+30)) {
            WhiteBall.ball.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);


           //  WhiteBall.speed(6);

        }

    Log.d("OnTouchPosition X",""+xpos);
    Log.d("OnTouchPosition Y",""+ypos);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In every touch, depending on what element was touched you should set a variable. For example in your code:

```
if (this.color == null) {
  this.color = Color.BLUE;
}
```

and when the other "thing" is touched you set the velocity:

```
else {
    this.velocity = 6;
    WhiteBall.ball.getPaint().setColor(this.color);
    WhiteBall.ball.setSpeed(this.velocity);
}
```